# Can someone give a good math/stats explanation as to what the parameter var_smoothing does for GaussianNB in scikit learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian

I am aware of this parameter var_smoothing and how to tune it, but I'd like an explanation from a math/stats aspect that explains what tuning it actually does - I haven't been able to find any good ones online.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A Gaussian curve can serve as a "low pass" filter, allowing only the samples close to its mean to "pass." In the context of Naive Bayes, assuming a Gaussian distribution is essentially giving more weights to the samples closer to the distribution mean. This might or might not be appropriate depending if what you want to predict follows a normal distribution.

The variable, var_smoothing, artificially adds a user-defined value to the distribution's variance (whose default value is derived from the training data set). This essentially widens (or "smooths") the curve and accounts for more samples that are further away from the distribution mean.

Comment: This is the best explanation I've come across so far.

Answer (score 4):

I have looked over the [Scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/naive_bayes.py) repository and found the following code and statement:

```
# If the ratio of data variance between dimensions is too small, it
# will cause numerical errors. To address this, we artificially
# boost the variance by epsilon, a small fraction of the standard
# deviation of the largest dimension.


self.epsilon_ = self.var_smoothing * np.var(X, axis=0).max()
```

In **Stats**, probability distribution function such as Gaussian depends on sigma^2 (variance); and the more variance between two features the less correlational and better estimator since naive Bayes as the model used is a iid (basically, it assume the feature are independent).

However, in terms computation, it is very common in machine learning that high or low values vectors or float operations can bring some errors, such as, "ValueError: math domain error". Which this extra variable may serve its purpose as a adjustable limit in case some-type numerical error occurred.

Now, it will be interesting to explore if we can use this value for further control such as avoiding over-fitting since this new self-epsilon is added into the variance(sigma^2) or standard deviations(sigma).